# VerticalFieldManager won't show scrollbar

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my blackberry app I have multiple cases where I have a scrolling VerticalFieldManager. They all scroll and behave correctly, but I can't seem to get any of them to show the scroll bar arrows. This is the code I am using to initialize them (They are all roughly the same)

```
VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
```

Any ideas? I don't understand why they won't show up.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

It was because while I had a VerticalFieldManager that took up the entire screen (called primary), which was intialized without scroll, I didn't actually call super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL).

So if anyone else stumbled here with the same problem, I couldn't get my children Managers to show a scroll bar, untill I called super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL), even if the elements I wanted to scroll were in a manager that had NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL set.

Answer (score 2):

The BlackBerry default scroll bar is two very small arrows (See the image below). My guess is you were expecting to see a rectangle down one side showing the percentage scrolled.

If this is the problem you might be interested in this more conventional implementation: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implementing-a-standard-style-scrollbar-on-a-Blackberry-device/ta-p/504416

[image: BlackBerry Scrollbars]

Comment: I was expecting the tiny arrows, I figured out the solution on my own though.
Thanks anyway though.